# Load a behavior extension from MEF plugin

Tags: wcf, mef

I am really hoping someone would have some input for my problem.

```
 MyApplication.exe
      |
      |
      |-Plugins (Folder)
           |
           |- Plugin1 (Folder)
           |     |
           |     |- MyPluginAssembly1.dll
                 |- MyPluginAssembly.AppConfig
           |
           |- Plugin2 (Folder)
                 |
                 |- MyPluginAssembly1.dll
                 |- Assembly1.dll
                 |- Assembly2.dll
```

The plugin I am trying to access is Plugin1 with a config file. 
The Plugin connects to some WCF services for another application which is not related to the MainApplication.

The config file has the following

```
 <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
       <add name="Version" type="SomeApplicaiton.MyClientBehaviorExtensionElement, Some-Application.App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>

    </extensions>
```

Plugin1 which has some  wcf services it needs to connect inorder to load. Problem is that it will not work if the behavior extension assemblies are located in the plugins folder. The .exe which is loading the plugin cannot load the assemblies unless they are registered or resides within the exe folder. 
On my development this works perfectly. But when the plugin is accessed, it gives me an error that the Version, MyClientBehaviorExtensionElement behavior extension cannot be loaded.

I have no control over the exe. Is there a way I can load this extension instead of putting the DLL in the exe folder

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sndr, resolveEventArgs) =>
{
    return Assembly.LoadFile(....._
}
```